# why two codes giving different output

Tags: c++

Are these two codes different?
if yes, then how?
if not, then why is same code giving different answers?

//[code 1](http://ideone.com/pgmqo7)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14

void fun() {
    printf("%f\n",PI);
}

int main() {
    printf("%f\n",PI);
    #define PI 3.141528
    fun();
}
```

**3.140000**

**3.140000**

//[code 2](http://ideone.com/I9B11X)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14

void fun();
 
int main() {
    printf("%f\n",PI);
    #define PI 3.141528
    fun();
}
 
void fun() {
    printf("%f\n",PI);
}
```

**3.140000**

**3.141528**

Or is it the issue with preprocessor directives?

Comment: Please put comments and reason if you are down voting this. There is no point in down voting without any comment.

Comment: Go through your code and replace `PI` with the value you've defined, as the preprocessor would. It's not hard to figure what's going on.

Comment: Your compiler should have given you a warning on the second `#define`.

Comment: no i just used ideone and no warning is issued there

Comment: @T.C. You don't see the warnings anymore if Ideone compiled an runs the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define` declares a preprocessor macro. Anytime the macro `PI` shows up in the code after `#define PI 3.14`, the preprocessor will change it to `3.14`, instead. In your first segment, you've defined it as `3.14`, and the preprocessor expands it to that everywhere. After you change the definition of `PI`, there is no mention of it anywhere, so the preprocessor never expands it to the new definition. However, in your second block, the preprocessor still expands the first `PI` to `3.14`, but now that the second occurence of `PI` occurs after the redefinition, it expands it to `3.141528`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, of course they do differ.
To the best of my knowledge, the scope of the constant defined using "#define" is from the line it is defined forward (until redefined or undefined, otherwise until the end of the code).
In the first program, the new PI is redefined and identified for only two lines after it:

```
...
#define PI 3.141528
fun();
}
```

But in the second one, it is redefined and identified for 6 lines after it:

```
...
#define PI 3.141528
fun();
}

void fun()
{
printf("%f\n",PI);
}
```

And it includes the body of fun(). So in the body of fun(), the new constant (3.141528) will be valid and applied.